# MultiThreadedMapper refuses to find Jar

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, emr

For some reason everytime I run this program (both on eclipse and on EMR) I get the message 13/07/18 13:22:23 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).  A few print statements later I find that my jarfile stubbornly remains null.  What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Job job = new Job();
            job.setJarByClass(Driver.Map.class);


             FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
             FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

            MultithreadedMapper.setMapperClass(job, Driver.Map.class);
            MultithreadedMapper.setNumberOfThreads(job, 64);

            job.setMapperClass(MultithreadedMapper.class);

            System.out.println(job.getJar());
            System.out.println(MultithreadedMapper.getNumberOfThreads(job) + "  "
                    + MultithreadedMapper.getMapperClass(job));

            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
            job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
            Config.LoggerProvider = LoggerProvider.DISABLED;


            job.waitForCompletion(true);


        }
```

Comment: I set it up to look for the driver and told it the package name, didnt help on eclipse but in emr it was able to find the jar.  Sadly it didnt seem to do anything with it.

Comment: Using some print statements i found everything as it should be but my mapper is still not getting called.